# How to calculate average per week in pyspark from a table?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

My table is like below:

```
+--------+-----+----+----------+
|  grDate|Items|rate|  unitName|
+--------+-----+----+----------+
|20131222|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131223|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131224|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131225|  SOY|34.0|Samastipur|
|20131225|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131227|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131228|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131229|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131230|  SOY|34.6|Samastipur|
|20131230|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20131231|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|
|20140101|  SOY|34.6|Samastipur|
|20140102|  SOY|34.6|Samastipur|
|20140103|  SOY|34.6|Samastipur|
|20140106|  SOY|34.6|Samastipur|
|20140107|  SOY|34.6|Samastipur|
|20140110|  SOY|33.9|Samastipur|
|20140111|  SOY|33.9|Samastipur|
|20140112|  SOY|33.9|Samastipur|
|20140113|  SOY|33.9|Samastipur|
+--------+-----+----+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

What I want is to calculate avg of rate column week wise and create a new table having those values.

I am trying to execute this query

```
spjsoya.createOrReplaceTempView("spjsoya")
spark.sql("SELECT grDate , (sum(total)/(WEEK(MAX(rate)) - WEEK(MIN(rate))+1)) AS rate FROM spjsoya  WHERE YEAR(grDate)='2013' GROUP BY grDate").show()
```

but it gives me error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'WEEK'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 29"
```

How can I write the correct query to take avg week wise ?

Comment: This is not a MySQL error message, therefore removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for your problem:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spjsoya.withColumn(
    'date_str',
    F.from_unixtime(
        F.unix_timestamp('a', 'yyyyMMdd')
    )
).withColumn(
    "week_num",
    F.weekofyear(F.col("date_str"))
).withColumn(
    "month",
    F.month(F.col("date_str"))
).withColumn(
    "year",
    F.year(F.col("date_str"))
).groupby(
    "year",
    "week_num"
).agg(
    F.avg("rate").alias("average_rate")
).orderBy(
    "week_num"
).show()
```

Comment: @ Ankit Kumar Namdeo thanks afor the action just to add my date are in string format, your answer is giving me answer like
20131222|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|              34.7|
|20131223|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|              34.7|
|20131224|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|              34.7|
|20131225|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|             34.35|
|20131225|  SOY|34.0|Samastipur|             34.35|
|20131227|  SOY|34.7|Samastipur|              34.7|

Comment: it wont matter, although if you want i can convert it .

Comment: @ Ankit Kumar Namdeo as you can see its gving avg on daily basis not on weekly basis,

Comment: no issues bro thansk for your help i am really stuck at this place and has very limited knowledge in pyspark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179321/discussion-between-raj-n-ish-ku-m-ar-and-ankit-kumar-namdeo).